# Return Observable in callback rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am messing around some with the google awareness api and now my understanding of RxJava is limiting me.

What I want to achieve in the end:
I want to get a Weather and a Location from the Api, and merge them into one object that I can pass on to my view for update.

However, I'm not sure how I achieve the returning of an Observable from the api callback here since it has void return type, and how to achieve merging of the weather and location object from api.getWeather and api.getLocation

```
public void requestUserCurrentInfo() {
    Subscription userInfo = getWeatherLocation().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(userinfo ->
                    Log.d(TAG,userinfo.something()));
}

public Observable<UserInfo> getWeatherLocation () {
    try {
        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(client)
                .setResultCallback(weather -> {
                    if (!weather.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Could not get weather");
                        return;
                    }
                    //How do I do here?
                    return weather.getWeather();
                });


        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getLocation(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(retrievedLocation -> {
                if(!retrievedLocation.getStatus().isSuccess()) return;
                Log.d("FRAG", retrievedLocation.getLocation().getLatitude() + "");
            });


    } catch (SecurityException exception) {
        throw new SecurityException("No permission " + exception);

    }

}
```

For my other things in my Project, I get some stuff through a REST api following the repository pattern, then I can get it like this because every step returns a Observable< SmhiResponse >

```
getWeatherSubscription = getWeatherUsecase.execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
                    smhiResponseModel -> {Log.d(TAG,"Retrieved weather"); locationView.hideLoading();},
                    err -> {Log.d(TAG,"Error fetching weather"); locationView.hideLoading();}
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return an observable from the callback but wrap your callbacks into observables to make them combinable (untested):

```
    Observable<WeatherResult> weatherObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(client)
                .setResultCallback(weather -> {
                    if (!weather.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        subscriber.onError(new Exception("Could not get weather."));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Could not get weather");
                    } else {
                        //How do I do here?

                        subscriber.onNext(weather);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
    });

    Observable<LocationResult> locationObservable = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Awareness.SnapshotApi.getLocation(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(retrievedLocation -> {
                    if(!retrievedLocation.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        subscriber.onError(new Exception("Could not get location."));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("FRAG", retrievedLocation.getLocation().getLatitude() + "");
                        subscriber.onNext(retrievedLocation);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                });
    });
```

now combine them via `.combineLatest()` or `.zip()`:

```
    Observable<CombinedResult> combinedResults = Observable.zip(weatherObservable, locationObservable,
            (weather, location) -> {
                /* somehow combine weather and location then return as type "CombinedResult" */
            });
```

don't forget to subscribe, otherwise none of them gets executed:

```
    combinedResults.subscribe(combinedResult -> {/*do something with that stuff...*/});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm and makes very much sense when you write it like this

Comment: Z How would I go about managing the unsubscribing in this case?

Comment: You don't need to. After termination (ie onError or onCompleted is executed on the Subscriber) unsubscribe wouldnt do anything anyway because you already received all elements (actually its just one) or an error was thrown. Either way the observable terminated...

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.combineLatest(getWeather (), getLocation(), new Func2<List<Object_A>, List<Object_B>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Object o, Object o2) {
                combine both results and return the combine result to observer
            }
        })
```

getweather() and  getlocation() return  observables

Comment: Not sure how you mean, The actual method from the api looks like


Awareness.SnapshotApi.getWeather(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<WeatherResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull WeatherResult weatherResult) {
                        if (!weatherResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Weather weather = weatherResult.getWeather();
                    }
                });

Comment: I mean getweather() and getlocation() should return an observable each and then use combinelatest to merge these two observable into one observable

Comment: Yes so far I am with you, but it complains when I try to return weather or location as an observable. 
How do I do it, with Observable.just(weather) or Observable.create... ?

Comment: My problem still lies that I can't return. If I make Observable.create(new Observable.onSubscribe<Weather> ...

The compiler will still say; 
Incompatible types: expected void but the lambda body is neither a statement nor a void compatible block